# ASP.NET multiple types of controls to insert a record

Tags: asp.net, detailsview, formview

ASP.NET newbie here. I would like to create a form with multiple types of controls for inserting a single record into a database table. This record has a "Type" field which is a foreign key, and I would like to populate a combobox with the possible values for it. I tried drag'n'dropping the table in design view (like in windows forms), but it always generates a gridview. How can I make it generate a form where I can specify the types of controls?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could check detailsview and formview control.
http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/QuickStart/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/detailsview.aspx

http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/QuickStart/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/formview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you either want to use a [DetailsView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx) or a [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.aspx) control.